# add home screen shortcut without toast message

Tags: android, xamarin

is there a way to add a homescreen shortcut without getting the toast message that the shortcut was added? Here is my method that adds the shortcut, but it is alway with a toast.

```
  private void AddShortcut()
    {
        var shortcutIntent = new Intent(this, typeof(ActivityMain));
        shortcutIntent.SetAction(Intent.ActionMain);

        var iconResource = Intent.ShortcutIconResource.FromContext(this, Resource.Drawable.ruwicon);

        var intent = new Intent();
        intent.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraShortcutIntent, shortcutIntent);
        intent.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraShortcutName, "My App");
        intent.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraShortcutIconResource, iconResource);
        intent.PutExtra("duplicate", false);
        intent.SetAction("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");
        SendBroadcast(intent);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, there is no way to prevent a default system Toast from appearing on the Screen, It has been officially said in [Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/Y6rhIXTMr8M)

[image]